# Bluetooth video streaming

Tags: java-me, bluetooth, video-streaming, java

Can anyone please direct me to learn something about Bluetooth video streaming programming using j2se and j2me technologies as i want to stream live video from pc to mobile phone through Bluetooth.

I am caputring video using jmf and then converting the captured video to 3gp format.
I want to stream this video to mobile phone(I have transferred stored video using OBEX protocol to mobile phone).

I have no idea about Bluetooth video streaming concept.

Any technical information would greatly help me.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

So you'd need to make a client/server connection between the PC and the mobile phone, using [JSR 82](http://www.jsr82.com/) (with an implementation such as [BlueCove](http://bluecove.org/) for the PC).  It's up to you whether the PC or the phone is the client or server, but plenty of examples of how to set it up [such as this one](http://www.jsr82.com/jsr-82-sample-spp-server-and-client).  If the handset supports JSR 82 but not OBEX, you'll need to implement that yourself too.

When you've figured out how to do an OBEX PUT of the file from PC to mobile, then for streaming, pass the InputStream into [`Manager.createPlayer()`](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr135/javax/microedition/media/Manager.html#createPlayer%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29), and you should have video streaming over Bluetooth.

HTH